# How to use the quote environment inside a \framebox?

Tags: boxes, framed, quoting

Now I run into a problem with frameboxes. Why is the following
not valid LaTeX code?

```
\framebox{
The following text was taken from:
\begin{quote}
Erik Pickles: How it will end
\end{quote}
}
```

I get the following error:

> something's wrong -- maybe an missing item?

Answer (score 12):

Framebox doesn't like have an environment inside it. You could consider using the `framed` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
Here is text
\begin{quote}
Here is quote
\end{quote}
\end{framed}
\end{document
```

Comment: "Framebox doesn't like have an environment inside it." Isn't correct like that. The issue isn't that `quote` is an environment but that `\framebox` forces horizontal mode for its content and `quote` likes to open a new paragraph and list which doesn't work in that mode.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to use a package as pointed out by Seamus you can use a minipage to do the trick.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\begin{document}
  \framebox{%
   \begin{minipage}{6cm}
    The following text was taken from:
    \begin{quote}
    Erik Pickles: How it will end
    \end{quote}
   \end{minipage}
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: This version has the advantage that the frame box doesn't extend all the way to the end of the frame. It does however have the disadvantage that you have to set the width manually...

Comment: @Seamus You're right, but you can always adapt to the default version of the  command by changing the `{6m}` to `{\textwidth}`

Comment: or you could do some fancy `\settowidth` magic to get the box to just surround the text you have... I actually think that would be a pretty elegant solution, but I can't work out how to make it into a macro easily...

Answer (score 3):

With package `varwidth` you do not have to know the width of the box

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
  \framebox{%
   \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}% the greatest possible line width
    The following text was taken from:
    \begin{quote}
    Erik Pickles: How it will end
    \end{quote}
   \end{varwidth}%
  }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to have it break across pages you can use the following.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\linewidth,fbox}
    The following text was taken from:
    \begin{quote}
    Erik Pickles: How it will end
    \end{quote}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

Otherwise use `framed` as Seamus suggested. Herbert's solution to use `varwidth` is also very good if you have not much text and want a tight frame around it.