# How to draw box around text that contains a verbatim block?

Tags: verbatim, framed

Typically, to box in some text, I use the following:

```
\fbox {
    \parbox{\linewidth}{
    This is some text! Blah blah blah...
    }
}
```

However, say I have a `verbatim` block within that. It will never compile. Anyone know how I could draw a box around text which contains a `verbatim` block?
I should note that I want to be able to draw a box around not just a `verbatim` block. For example, I would want to draw a box around something like:

```
This is text.
\begin{verbatim}
This is some more text.
\end{verbatim}
And this is even more text.
```

Answer (score 35):

If you just want to frame a `verbatim` block, you may consider using the [fancyvrb](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
abc
def
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16):

[`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) can also draw boxes around `verbatim` text

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

This is text.

\begin{tcolorbox}
This is text.
\begin{verbatim}
This is some more text.
     This is a second line #/&
\end{verbatim}
And this is even more text.
\end{tcolorbox}

And this is even more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Yet another solution `:)` is to use the `cprotect` package ([on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cprotect/))

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{cprotect}
\begin{document}

\cprotect\fbox{
  \begin{minipage}{4cm}
    This some normal text and 
    this is verbatim 
    \verb|demonstration text|\\
    \verb|demonstration text|
  \end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

Note that the `minipage` is not part of the answer: it allows several lines in the `\fbox`.

Answer (score 8):

The `framed` package defines a `framed` environment that can contain verbatim text. This is a nice option if you want text other than the verbatim environment to be in the box.

See also answers to [How to use the quote environment inside a \framebox?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6228/215)

Comment: There is also the (IMHO better) `mdframed` package.

Answer (score 4):

Willie's answer using the `fancyvrb` is a common way out of this. If you are inserting code you could also list at the `listings` package. You can also use the `verbdef` package that allows you to define commands that contain verbatim text.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{verbdef}
\begin{document}
\verbdef\demo{demonstration text}
\framebox{
 \begin{minipage}{4cm}
 This some normal text and 
 this is verbatim 
 \demo\\
 \demo\\
 \end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `verbbox` environment of the `verbatimbox` package puts verbatim into a box that can then be recalled elsewhere, in places where verbatim environment is not allowed (such as tabular, footnotes, fboxes, etc. [A new version of `verbatimbox` should be coming out in the coming days]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}
This is some more text.
\end{verbbox}
\fbox{
This is text.
\theverbbox
And this is even more text.
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've got another solution which might be not useful in most cases, but in my case it is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\draw [very thick] (0,-0.5) rectangle (2,0.5);
\node at (1,0) {\verb+\text+};
\end{tikzpicture}
```