# Frame around minipage containing listing in beamer

Tags: beamer, listings, minipage, framed

I am working on the sheets of a course on LaTeX and would like to have several sheets in which you see on the left an example of a source document and on the right its output. I have this working now with listings and minipage, but I also want a frame around the page of a fixed width and height.

what I have now is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{The \LaTeX\ language}

% Source code:
\begin{columns}[T]
\column{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\LaTeX\ code:
%\begin{lrbox}\mylistingbox
\begin{minipage}[t][0.7\textheight]{\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
An equation:
\[
  1 + 1 = 2
\]
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
%\end{lrbox}
%\fbox{\usebox\mylistingbox}
\end{center}

% Output
\column{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{center}
Output:
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t][0.7\textheight]{1\textwidth}
An equation:
\[
  1 + 1 = 2
\]
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This works, but only puts a frame around the right side (the output). If I try the same with `\fbox{}` on the left side it does not work.

How can I put a frame around the minipage with the listiting?

Comment: Now I found this possible duplicate question: [How to draw box around text that contains a verbatim block.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6260/2975)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this does not address you specific question, I would highly recommend that you consider using [the `showexpl` pacakge](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/showexpl) which makes use of the `listings` package.   This eliminates the duplication of the LaTeX code, so it is not as error prone.

To control the font use `basicstyle=...` to set it for the listings.  The output font will be as per the rest of the document. If you want to adjust it just for the output of `LTXexample` you can use `preset=...` to specify commands to be executed before the sample code is typeset.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showexpl}% already includes listings package

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\lstdefinestyle{demoLatexStyle}{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,% control font of code
    preset=\small,% adjust font size of output
    numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=2, numbersep=5pt,
    frame=tlbr,
    pos=r,% want output on right
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!30},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    width=0.50\linewidth,
}
\lstloadlanguages{[LaTeX]TeX}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{The \LaTeX\ language}
\makebox[0.50\linewidth][c]{\LaTeX\ code:}%  Center titles over
\makebox[0.50\linewidth][c]{Output:}%        half the \linewidth

\begin{LTXexample}[style=demoLatexStyle]
An equation:
\[
  1 + 1 = 2
\]
\end{LTXexample}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. Is there a way to make the font in the output abit smaller?

Comment: Use `\preset` to specify commands to be executed prior to typesetting the code. See updated example.

Answer (score 7):

You can't have verbatim material inside a macro argument. You need to box the content first as you already did in your commented-out code. I wrote the `realboxes` package to provide variant of most `\XXXbox` macros which box their "argument". In your case simply load `realboxes` and use `\Fbox` instead of `\fbox`. There should be also a `%` after the `{` to avoid getting a space there from the following newline.

```
\usepackage{realboxes}
%...

\Fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t][0.7\textheight]{1\textwidth}
An equation:
\[
  1 + 1 = 2
\]
\end{minipage}}
```

There is also a `Fbox` environment.

You could also use my `adjustbox` package:

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
% ...

\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t][0.7\textheight]{1\textwidth},fbox}
An equation:
\[
  1 + 1 = 2
\]
\end{adjustbox}
```

There are many other keys (options) you can add, e.g. `center` to center the content etc.

Finally, there are also the `framed` and (better) `mdframed` packages which provide an environment for frames.