# asme y14.5 symbols & feature control frame

Tags: technical-drawing

I have used LaTeX a little bit for math (one Ipython notebook assignment to be exact).

I am a draftsman, I have been searching for a LaTeX library to do asme y14.5 symbols in LaTeX. I haven't found one for asme y14.5 symbols yet, however most of the symbols seem to be available in one form or another.

here is a Wikipedia page that has a chart of the basic symbols
[Wikipedia GD&T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_dimensioning_and_tolerancing).

however I am most interested in is how I might emulate a [feature control frame](https://joesorrent.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/feature-control-frame-datum-order-of-precedence.jpg) which is a series of boxes that wrap around your symbols and text. These boxes can be stacked as well as be merged vertically on the first box.

So my specific questions are:
Q1 is there a way to create boxes around text and symbols using some kind of begin and end tags.

Q2 if there is not a way to do this library for LaTeX would such a thing be feasible by designing a font & programming.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no such font in latex. You can, however, install truetype fonts.
First you'll need a font, you can find it anywhere on the internets, [here is an example](http://www.fontspace.com/category/gdt).

Then you'll need to use the font, [Here's how](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236/90297).

As for the box, I'm not sure whether you'll need it with this font... There are boxes defined in the font (see 0123-0124). But if you decide on another font, or think that the boxes are not good enough, [you can see here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes) how to create a box around your text. or you could use [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6260/how-to-draw-box-around-text-that-contains-a-verbatim-block).